# Link with anchor to different page (href)

Tags: html, anchor, href

I have a page with **working anchors** like these:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#ta-services">Leistungen</a>
...
<section class="border-top" id="ta-services">
```

On another page, I want to link to the first page at the same anchors position. In my understanding, that should be possible with plain html:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="index.html#ta-services">Leistungen</a>
```

However, the link works just like a normal link to index.html, the page does not scroll down. Example online at http://elisabethzenz.at/impressum_datenschutz.html. Link in the upper right named "Leistungen".

The website is based on a bootstrap template, it might be some interference with the full screen header image – I would appreciate any hints how to solve the issue!

Comment: -  I would suggest you try `<a class="nav-link" href="index.html/#ta-services">Leistungen</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native navigation to fragment works correctly. You have some JavaScript that scrolls the page to top when the URL has a hash component.

In `assets/js/theme.js` around line `702`:

```
  var hash = window.location.hash;

  if (hash && document.getElementById(hash.slice(1))) {
    var $this = $(hash);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $this.offset().top - $("a[href='" + hash + "']").data('offset')
    }, 400, 'swing', function () {
      window.history.pushState ? window.history.pushState(null, null, hash) : window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  }
```

`$("a[href='" + hash + "']").data('offset')` returns undefined,
so `scrollTop: NaN` = `scrollTop: 0`

You could just remove all that code, and it will work.

Or make sure that operation doesn't return NaN:

```
scrollTop: $this.offset().top - ($("a[href='" + hash + "']").data('offset') || 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

You have a sizeable amount of JS that's delaying the loading of the page. The browser looks for the `#ta-services` on initial load and doesn't see it, so it stops.

You need to use JS to scroll to the position after everything has finished loading. You can do this with some JS that looks like this:

```js
document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Put this in your JS to run after the page has loaded. If you don't already have something like that, you can use:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  // Scroll into view code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea – I already did try that at the end of index.html (including coloring for debug purpose), no scrolling either. 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
        document.getElementById('ta-services').scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
        document.getElementById('ta-services').style.background = '#ff0000';
      });
    </script>
(And second, using a method like these, I would need to include more logic and parse the url; I am looking for a native way without additional JS)

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll need to use JS due to the slow loading of the site, you can't rely on the "native way". Without seeing the rest of your JS and what other events you're hooking into, I can't tell you exactly where to place this code to make it work, but that's the code you'll need.

Comment: Still working on the issue; JS is active and triggered (color coding and showing an alert) but no scrolling. Will try again next weekend.

Comment: I have copied your files to my local machine and removed all the stylesheets. There, the page actually does scroll to the specific anchor (*Leistungen*, *Kontakt) but only for a fraction of a second. It immediatly scrols back to the top; so there is probably something else going on...

Answer (score 3):

Based on ***Caleb Anthony***'s answer:

You can scroll to `#ta-services` using JavaScript after the page loads:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('ta-services').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
});
```

The difference between `load` and `DOMContentLoaded` events is explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) as

> The **load** event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images. This is in contrast to **DOMContentLoaded**, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading.

Thus, when `DOMContentLoaded` event fires, the positions of elements are not final.

Answer (score 2):

@Markus Proske below script will help you.
**Script of navbar** **to jump to respective section form the another page**

Here i have define navigation script.

---

```
$('.nav-link').on('click', function (event) {
    var $anchor = $(this);
     $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
     }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

---

For Example here i have given navigation structure, i.e,

```
 <!-- Homepage "index.html"--> 
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu menu-main">
      <li class="nav-link"> <a href="#home"><span>Home</span></a> </li> <!-- index.html -->      
      <li class="nav-link"> <a href="about-us.html"><span>About Us</span></a> </li> <!-- separate page -->
      <li class="nav-link"> <a href="#contact"><span>Contact Us</span></a> </li>            
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Homepage has below sections "index.html"-->
  <section id="home"></section>
  <section id="contact"></section>


 <!-- About-Us Page -->
  <nav id="menu">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu menu-main">
      <li class="nav-link"> <a href="index.html#home"><span>Home</span></a> </li> <!-- index.html -->      
      <li class="nav-link"> <a href="about-us.html"><span>About Us</span></a> </li>            
      <li class="nav-link"> <a href="index.html#contact"><span>Contact Us</span></a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: It is good practise, that event.preventDefault() to be define on very first line on event definition.

Answer (score 1):

Add following script code & update html code of the navigation link for "Leistungen" menu

```js
$(document).on('click',"#goto-services",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#ta-services").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="#ta-services" id="goto-services">Leistungen</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

## **It is working as expected but...**

#link is working as expected. The browser is actually scrolling the page to the given id but instantly scrolling document to the top. May be some of your JS code is scrolling your page to top.

If you open this page and keep eye on the scrollbar than you can notice the scrollbar behavior. It first scrolled to the given id i.e. #ta-services and at the same time moving scrollbar to the top.

You need to find out JS code which is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you have jQuery.

You can add this code snippet just before your `body` tag closes.

```
<script> 
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I removed all of your JS, it works as intended. I commented out all of your preloaders, scripts, bootstrap, etc. Most of what people are suggesting here has already been done there, so I believe you're good on that front. Your anchor link works when we take the JS out of the picture.

We know the problem is one of the libraries/scripts you are using, so that's one step closer.

Could we sequentially start drilling down to the issue by removing the likely culprits (like your lazy loaders?) one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in scrolling functionality of anchor.

page1.html

```
<a href="page2.html#Anchorname">go to page 2</a>
<a name="Anchorname"></a>
```

page2.html

```
<a href="page1.html#Anchorname">goto page 1</a>
<a name="Anchorname"></a>
```